# How do you use the zfs encryption recovery key 22.04

Tags: data-recovery, zfs

I've installed ubuntu 22.4 using the graphical installer.
I chose to use a ZFS root install with encryption using the GUI options (without doing the advanced stuff). At some part of the process I recorded a "recovery key" - 48 digits (i.e. 0 -> 9). How do you use that key?

Thanks !

Comment: One of the only times you’ll use that is if you need to mount the encrypted ZFS volumes on a different machine. You can think of a ZFS key the same as a password-protected SSH key; the password you type is for humans and the key itself is for machines 

Comment: If i understand, the recovery.key will be usefull if my motherboard crash and i need to recovery the data on the hdd ? 
i'll put the hdd on other computer, and une the recovery key to mount the hdd on the new computer and i'll need to use the "human" password to uncrypt the data ?

Comment: Correct. When you mount an encrypted ZFS volume, you'll pass the key (stored in a file with `600` permissions) as part of the mount command. Then the system will load the key and ask you for the password. So long as the password is correct, the key will be correctly deciphered, added to the local ZFS key store, and the volume will be decrypted and mounted.